# Why does a void method return value.C# language

Tags: c#, methods

```
static void Main(string[] arts)

          Int X=5;

          Change number(ref X);
   
          Console.WriteLine(X);
   
          Console.ReadKey();


static void ChangeNumber(ref int y)

          y=0;

         // No return statement
```

This program works, it's output is 0. My question is :: Why does the method return a value(y), when it actually doesn't have a return statement, since it's even a void method.

Comment: For future reference, be sure that code you post here actually compiles and runs. Your current code example has many syntax errors so that it won't even run. These kinds of errors often make it difficult to answer questions.

Comment: Because you used ref in your input which is manipulate your reference variable!

Comment: Please Read This Post About By Ref Logic: MDSN By Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Answer (score 1):

The method does not "return" a value.  Instead, the parameter is getting changed and because of the use of the [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword that change is reflected in the original variable:

> When used in a method's parameter list, the ref keyword indicates that
> an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The ref keyword
> makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a
> variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on
> the argument. For example, if the caller passes a local variable
> expression or an array element access expression, and the called
> method replaces the object to which the ref parameter refers, then the
> caller's local variable or the array element now refers to the new
> object when the method returns.

This is known as "passing an argument by reference".  Without the `ref` keyword, only the local variable would be changed in the method and the original variable would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The method `ChangeNumber()` does **not** return a value, like you say. To return a value, we must use the `return` keyword and assign the returned value to a variable at the point of the function call:

```
static void Main(string[] arts) {

          Int X=5;

          Console.WriteLine(X);

          x = ChangeNumber();
   
          Console.WriteLine(X);
   
          Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ChangeNumber() {

          return 0;

         // No return statement
}
```

Instead, your example accepts a parameter **by reference** and changes the value of that parameter. I suggest that you read about the difference between "pass by reference" and "pass by value".

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the "The programm exited with return code 0"-like message in the console, please read this [documentation about return values of the Main-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/main-return-values), the returned `0` is an implicit value:

> If the return value from Main is not used, returning void allows for slightly simpler code. However, returning an integer enables the program to communicate status information to other programs or scripts that invoke the executable file. ***The return value from Main is treated as the exit code for the process. If void is returned from Main, the exit code will be implicitly 0.***

Answer (score 0):

The method is not returning any value, its basically updating the `ref` parameter if you changing it inside the method.

I would suggest you go through this article once.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref